# How to handle multiple leaderboards with Steamwork.net unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, steam, steamworks-api

Following the various example it is always shown a single leaderboard case.

Here the leaderboard handle is stored...

```
private SteamLeaderboard_t m_currentLeaderboard;
```

after the LeaderboardFindResult_t callback is returned

```
void OnLeaderboardFindResult(LeaderboardFindResult_t pCallback, bool bIOFailure)
{
    if (pCallback.m_bLeaderboardFound != 0)
    {
            m_currentLeaderboard = pCallback.m_hSteamLeaderboard;
```

I really can't understand how to handle a case with multiple leaderboards... I thought to use multiple handles like:

```
private SteamLeaderboard_t m_Leaderboard_one;
private SteamLeaderboard_t m_Leaderboard_two;
```

and calling multiple times something like:

```
SteamAPICall_t handle = SteamUserStats.FindLeaderboard(THE_LEADERBOAR_NAME_I_WANT);
OnLeaderboardFindResultCallResult.Set(handle);
```

but it is clear that it is not working like that since the `OnLeaderboardFindResult`, even if I call FindLeaderboard multiple times with different boards it is called just once... so I'm wondering how could I refer to different leaderboard?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the callresults.

Steamworks API needs you to store the callResults to prevent garbage collection as it stated in the [documentation](https://steamworks.github.io/gettingstarted/#steam-callresults).

So you need to store each callResult separately. You can hold them in a list for example:

```
 private static List<CallResult<LeaderboardFindResult_t>> m_findResult_list = new List<CallResult<LeaderboardFindResult_t>>();
```

And on Start you can basically do something like this for each one of the leaderboards:

```
 SteamAPICall_t hsteamAPICall = SteamUserStats.FindLeaderboard(leaderboardType.ToString());
 CallResult<LeaderboardFindResult_t> findResult = new CallResult<LeaderboardFindResult_t>();
 findResult.Set(hsteamAPICall, OnLeaderBoardFound);
    
 m_findResult_list.Add(findResult);
```